# How do I resolve error installing manim using poetry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry, manim, pangocairo

I want to setup manim community repo using poetry. I ran the command "poetry install". I am getting the following error.
Python 3.8.5, Pip 20.2.4

```
  EnvCommandError

  Command D:\manim\venv\Scripts\pip.exe install --no-deps file:///C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/artifacts/03/ee/1a/ee5da5d7b449da38c4e593ecc6a57342de04222cd7fbe5b126a4e3f
df0/pangocairocffi-0.3.2.tar.gz errored with the following return code 1, and output:
  Processing c:\users\abc\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\artifacts\03\ee\1a\ee5da5d7b449da38c4e593ecc6a57342de04222cd7fbe5b126a4e3fdf0\pangocairocffi-0.3.2.tar.gz
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

                         ...
                         ...
                         ...

      OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: pango / pango-1 / pango-1.0 / pango-1.0-0
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use poetry only when you want to contribute to [Manim Community](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/) itself, or else don't use it.

Now let's, come to the error. What the error, say's is it can't find some shared libraries. According to the [docs](https://docs.manim.community/en/latest/installation/win.html#pango-installation), it says, you have to install Pango for it to work.

Possibly, you may have missed this step.
https://docs.manim.community/en/latest/installation/win.html#pango-installation

Comment: this is exactly right. I hadn't set up pango properly. thank you for answering.